# Latex error: Table label is undefined

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, captions, labels

I generated some tables with Stata for inclusion in my Latex report. However, for two regression tables, no matter what I do, I cannot refer to these tables. I have successfully generated several tables of summary statistics with the same Stata package, using the same dataset, which I could successfully reference.

Here is my table code:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Some caption \label{tab:Overlap-Reg-Results-Tuned}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Var 1}                   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Var 2}              &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Var 3}                 \\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         \\
\midrule
Hello                &       1.27\sym{***}&       1.044\sym{***}&       849.3\sym{***}&       129.3\sym{**}&      0.0215         &      0.0196         \\
                    &     (0.156)         &     (0.163)         &     (15.99)         &     (16.10)         &    (1.016)         &    (0.0122)         \\
Simsalabim            &      -2.296\sym{***}&      -2.202\sym{***}&      -272.8\sym{***}&      -201.0\sym{**}&       0.106\sym{***}&       0.153\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0653)         &    (0.0893)         &     (24.63)         &     (20.92)         &    (0.0260)         &    (0.0203)         \\
Treatment Effect x&       1.300\sym{}&       1.278\sym{***}&       -154.9\sym{*}&       147.5\sym{**}&     -0.0653\sym{***}&     -0.0711\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.266)         &     (0.271)         &     (32.94)         &     (33.04)         &    (0.0169)         &    (0.0175)         \\
Bond $<$ Min.wage&      -1.242\sym{***}&      -1.095\sym{***}&      -557.2\sym{***}&      -536.5\sym{***}&      -0.604\sym{***}&      -0.550\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.140)         &     (0.271)         &     (14.57)         &     (33.19)         &    (0.122)         &    (0.0329)         \\
Treatment y&       0.525         &       0.409         &      -54.57         &      -57.49         &     0.0318         &     -0.0257         \\
                    &     (0.464)         &     (0.442)         &     (54.13)         &     (72.67)         &    (0.0455)         &    (0.0456)         \\
Non-binding &      -0.179         &      -0.394         &      -657.0\sym{***}&      247.8\sym{***}&      -1.165\sym{***}&      -1.093\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.156)         &     (0.200)         &     (17.27)         &     (31.34)         &    (0.0265)         &    (0.0377)         \\
xyz&      -0.738         &      -0.711         &      -15.6\sym{*}  &      -110.6\sym{*}  &       0.205\sym{***}&       0.212\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.420)         &     (0.417)         &     (4.6)         &     (4.4)         &    (0.969)         &    (0.0495)         \\
Constant            &       9.233\sym{***}&       8.354\sym{***}&      105.3\sym{***}&       820.7\sym{***}&       3.332\sym{**}&       2.971\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0190)         &     (0.65)         &     (9.85)         &     (156.3)         &    (0.0220)         &     (0.162)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &        231         &        2831         &        3431         &        2151         &        2431         &        2431         \\
\(R^{2}\)           &       0.24         &       0.413         &       0.602         &       0.722         &       0.365         &       0.522         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &       0.176         &       0.101         &       0.300         &       0.444         &       0.6         &       0.515         \\
Controls            &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize SEs are clustered on individuals. Controls as outlined in ...}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize F-Test ...}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

I use the booktabs package. The code to include the table & refer it to is as follows:

```
Some other stuff..
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \include{05-Tables/My-Table}
\end{table}

Now I want to refer to the table using \ref{tab:Overlap-Reg-Results-Tuned}.
```

However, all Latex shows me are two ?? and the error message "Reference tab:Overlap-Reg-Results-Tuned on page x undefined on input line y".

Where am I going wrong? I tried changing the compiler, Google or Stack had no answers I could find.

Comment: that should be a warning not an error, what happens if you run latex again?

Comment: oh but `\include` is wrong there never use `\include`  except at the top level. Use `\input`. `\include` always implies a new page, such as a chapter opening

Comment: Oh my god that solved it, thank you so much! Yes, it was a warning, my apologies. Replacing include with input makes it work. Hero!

Answer (score 1):

`\include` is only for including chapter-like chunks of a document and interacts with `\includeonly` so that you can just process parts of a documentto speed up drafts.

Use `\input` to include fragments of a document in other places such as this table.